# Micronaut: JsonProperty missing in OpenAPI Generator for serializationLibrary micronaut_serde_jackson

Tags: json-deserialization, micronaut, openapi-generator

We are generating Micronaut code from OpenApi files using the OpenApi Generator. When using Jackson as a serialization library this works fine, but when we try to switch to Micronaut Serialization and using serializationLibrary micronaut_serde_jackson then the @JsonProperty annotations are missing from the generated code. This makes it impossible to deserialize documents using the generated code when the documents does not follow a strict camel case notation.

Documents like this will for instance fail to deserialize (and in my case changing this document to using more standard field names is not an option):

```
{
    "my_name": "My name"
}
```

I have created an issue for this against the OpenAPI Generator:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/16939. I am not sure how fast this will be fixed however, and we are really eager at switching over to Micronaut Serialization.

Has anybody experienced the same and has a workaround, or do we need to wait for the OpenApi generator to be fixed?